# MySQL: sumar agrupado por intervalos de tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en MySQL que tiene 3 campos: fecha, hora e importe. Dicha información corresponde a los
remitos emitidos desde el 01/01/2022 hasta la fecha actual (la que sea, pongamos 11/07/2023). Se me pidió un
formulario en el cual se pueda indicar una fecha y hora de inicio, una fecha y hora de final y un intervalo de tiempo
y que para cada intervalo muestre la suma de los remitos.
O sea, si el usuario ingresa:

```
fecha de inicio: 01/01/2022
hora de inicio: 09:00
fecha de final: 30/06/2023
hora de final: 21:30
intervalo: 30 minutos
```

El resultado debe ser (números ficticios):

```
01/01/2022 9:00 - 9:30: 34587  
01/01/2022 9:31 - 10:00: 95218
```

Y así sucesivamente para cada intervalo de tiempo. Conseguir la consulta básica es fácil:

```
select fecha, hora, importe 
from latabla 
where fecha >= '2022-01-01' and 
    fecha <= '2023-07-11' and 
    hora >= '09:00:00' and 
    hora <= '21:30:00'
```

Para conseguir la suma de cada intervalo, ejecuto esa consulta modificando el intervalo de horas. Eso resulta en una cantidad enorme de consultas. Me preguntaba cómo hacer una única consulta que me devuelva el resultado esperado y no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo, si es que se puede hacer con una única consulta.

Mooochas graceas!

Comment: ¿Qué opciones de intervalo puede elegir el usuario, o es totalmente arbitrario? Por otro lado, la consulta básica tampoco es tan sencilla como la que propones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, se puede. Pero previamente necesitas definir los intervalos de tiempo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS intervalos(
  id_intervalo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  f_ini date,
  f_fin date,
  h_ini time,
  h_fin time
  );
INSERT INTO intervalos (f_ini, f_fin, h_ini, h_fin) VALUES
  ('2023-07-09','2023-07-10','10:00','11:00'),
  ('2023-07-11','2023-07-12','12:00','13:00');
```

Entiendo que partes de un dataset como el que describes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS latabla(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha date,
  hora time,
  importe float
  );
INSERT INTO latabla (fecha, hora, importe) VALUES
  ('2023-07-09','10:00',10),
  ('2023-07-10','11:00',20),
  ('2023-07-11','12:00',30),
  ('2023-07-12','13:00',40);
```

Con esta consulta:

```
SELECT *
  FROM latabla
  JOIN intervalos
  ON fecha BETWEEN f_ini AND f_fin
  AND hora BETWEEN h_ini AND h_fin;
```

Conseguirías el resultado que esperas:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| id | fecha      | hora     | importe | id_intervalo | f_ini      | f_fin      | h_ini    | h_fin    |
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2023-07-09 | 10:00:00 |      10 |            1 | 2023-07-09 | 2023-07-10 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
|  2 | 2023-07-10 | 11:00:00 |      20 |            1 | 2023-07-09 | 2023-07-10 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
|  3 | 2023-07-11 | 12:00:00 |      30 |            2 | 2023-07-11 | 2023-07-12 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
|  4 | 2023-07-12 | 13:00:00 |      40 |            2 | 2023-07-11 | 2023-07-12 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
+----+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Y, con esta otra, podrías incluso totalizar los importes por cada uno de los intervalos:

```
SELECT * FROM intervalos JOIN (
    SELECT id_intervalo,SUM(importe) importe
      FROM latabla
      JOIN intervalos
      ON fecha BETWEEN f_ini AND f_fin
      AND hora BETWEEN h_ini AND h_fin
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(id_intervalo);

+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
| id_intervalo | f_ini      | f_fin      | h_ini    | h_fin    | importe |
+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
|            1 | 2023-07-09 | 2023-07-10 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |      30 |
|            2 | 2023-07-11 | 2023-07-12 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |      70 |
+--------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Lo que cuesta ver de esta consulta es que es posible combinar por cualquier dato, como en este caso la fecha y la hora, y no únicamente por `id`, como suele ser lo habitual.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: El intervalo, así como las fechas y horas, quedan a completo criterio del usuario, por lo que no sé de antemano ningún dato... tal vez con alguna tabla temporal y algo de código en PHP...?

Comment: Entendí que los intervalos los definías tú. Si te los define el usuario, siempre puedes insertar los datos que te proporciones en la tabla `intervalos` con un simple formulario.

Comment: Finalmente lo he resuelto en base a esta respuesta: creo una tabla temporal (ligeramente diferente a la propuesta) donde preparo los intervalos  y con un par de pequeños ajustes a la 2da consulta consigo los resultados esperados. Solo me falta el ajuste fino de los intervalos de tiempo, restar (o sumar) 1 minuto para evitar sumar dos veces el importe. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podemos generar *al vuelo* una *tabla* de intervalos que utilizar para producir el resultado deseado. Los elementos necesarios son:

- Que todo dependa de una variable, la llamaremos `@MinutosIntervalo` y tendrá un número entero que indica la cantidad de minutos que tiene cada intervalo. Con solo cambiar el valor de dicha variable, se producirá un resultado ajustado a dicho valor.
- Para lograrlo, necesitamos generar una serie de números consecutivos de 1 a N, dónde N sea suficiente para cubrir el máximo de intervalos posibles a generar. Si el intervalo mínimo es de 1 minuto y las horas disponibles son las 24 horas del día, hablamos de un máximo de 1440 intervalos.

  Para generar esta serie, en el ejemplo a continuación me valgo de la función de ventana [`row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) y de la tabla del diccionario de datos `information_schema.columns`, que suele tener suficientes filas en una instalación típica de mySQL. Hay otras maneras de producir una secuencia de números, así que puedes cambiarla si tienes otra que sea más conveniente.
- Sobre esta serie de números consecutivos, podemos ir calculando la hora de inicio y fin de cada intervalo a considerar. Yo lo he hecho de esta forma:

  - Primero tengo una variable llamada `@MinutosIntervalo` que tiene el número de minutos que dura cada uno de los intervalos y otra variable llamada `@HoraIni` que tiene la hora de inicio de la consulta.
  - Con esto puedo calcular, para cada fila de la tabla de intervalos, los minutos que hay que sumarle a la hora de inicio para obtener la hora de inicio del intervalo y los minutos que hay que sumarle a la hora de inicio para obtener la hora de fin del intervalo. Si pudieramos sumar directamente minutos a una hora, estos serían:

    - `@HoraInicio + (N - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo` me daría la hora inicial del intervalo N
    - `@HoraInicio + N * @MinutosIntervalo` me daría la hora final del intervalo
  - Dado que no puedo sumar directamente minutos, me puedo valer de la función [`addtime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) para sumar una cantidad arbitraria a la hora de inicio de la consulta. Esta función puede recibir un entero de la forma `hhmmss`, es decir, si se le pasa el número `013000` es interpretado como `01:30:00` (una hora con 30 minutos).
  - Como ya tengo el número de minutos, puedo convertir este número en uno de la forma `hhmmss` con operaciones aritméticas básicas (división entera, residuo, multiplicación y suma).

    En resumen partiendo de TotalMinutos, abreviado como `tm`:

    `hhmmss = (tm div 60) * 10000 + (tm % 60) * 100`

    Por ejemplo, 200 minutos son 3 horas y 20 minutos:

    `(200 div 60) * 10000 + (200 % 60) * 100`

    `= 3 * 10000 + 20 * 100`

    `= 30000 + 2000`

    `= 32000`

    Equivalente a `03:20:00`

    Puedo aplicar esta fórmula para calcular la hora a sumar a la hora inicial, pero dado que queremos evitar los traslapes, aprovecho para restarle un segundo a la hora final, con lo que para la hora final, me quedo con:

    `hhmmss = ((tm - 1) div 60) * 10000 + ((tm - 1) % 60) * 100 + 59`

    Por ejemplo, 200 minutos son 3 horas y 20 minutos, menos un segundo, son `02:19:59`

    `((200 - 1) div 60) * 10000 + ((200 - 1) % 60) * 100 + 59`

    `= (199 div 60) * 10000 + (199 % 60) * 100 + 59`

    `= 3 * 10000 + 19 * 100 + 59`

    `= 30000 + 1900 + 59`

    `= 31959`

    Equivalente a `03:19:59`
- Poniendo todo lo dicho hasta aquí en una consulta SQL, podría calcular intervalos al vuelo con algo como esto:

  ```
  set @MinutosIntervalo := 20; 
  set @HoraIni := cast('08:00:00' as time);
  select   @HoraIni
         , GenInt.NumIntervalo
         , (GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo MinutosSumaInicio
         , GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo MinutosSumaFin
         , ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) div 60 * 10000 + ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) % 60 * 100 NumeroSumaInicio
         , (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) div 60 * 10000 + (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) % 60 * 100 + 59 NumeroSumaFin
         , addtime(@HoraIni, ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) div 60 * 10000 + ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) % 60 * 100) InicioIntervalo
         , addtime(@HoraIni, (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) div 60 * 10000 + (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) % 60 * 100 + 59) FinIntervalo
  from (select row_number() over (order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as NumIntervalo from information_schema.columns) as GenInt
  ```
- Ahora se hace necesario limitar el número de intervalos que contiene la tabla *al vuelo*. Para ello necesitamos definir la hora fin de la consulta y calcular cuantos intervalos hay entre la hora de inicio y la hora fin. Para ello podemos valernos de [`timediff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) que nos devuelve la diferencia entre 2 horas, siempre en tipo de dato `time`, y sobre este resultado con [`hour()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) y [`minute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) podemos extraer la información que nos interesa, por ejemplo con este cálculo:

  ```
  set @MinutosIntervalo := 20; 
  set @HoraIni := cast('08:00:00' as time);
  set @HoraFin := cast('17:30:00' as time);
  set @IntervaloDia := timediff(@HoraFin, @HoraIni);
  set @MinutosTotales = hour(@IntervaloDia) * 60 + minute(@IntervaloDia);
  set @Intervalos = @MinutosTotales / @MinutosIntervalo;
  ```

  Obtendríamos un resultado de 28.5 intervalos.
- Vamos a generar el número exacto de intervalos si nos devuelve un entero y si no siempre vamos a generar uno más.

Finalmente, estamos listos para producir la solución final, aún hay un par de cosas a considerar:

- Voy a colocar en un CTE la consulta que genera *al vuelo* la tabla de intervalos.
- Para relacionar la tabla de datos con estos intervalos, la cláusula del *join* no será de igualdad, sino un operador *between* entre la hora de la entrada del *remito* y la hora inicial y final del intervalo.
- Finalmente, aplicamos las funciones `count()` y `sum()` para calcular la agregación y una cláusula `group by` sobre la fecha y la hora inicial y final del intervalo relacionado.

Como siempre, el código dice mas que mil palabras.

He tomado prestada la definición de tabla que se usó en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/598846/21) a esta misma pregunta, solo he añadido algunas filas adicionales.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS latabla(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha date,
  hora time,
  importe float
  );
INSERT INTO latabla (fecha, hora, importe) VALUES
    ('2023-07-09','10:00', 10)
  , ('2023-07-09','10:15', 15)
  , ('2023-07-09','11:15', 15)
  , ('2023-07-09','11:25', 10)
  , ('2023-07-09','11:30', 15)
  , ('2023-07-10','11:00', 20)
  , ('2023-07-11','12:00', 30)
  , ('2023-07-12','13:00', 40)
  , ('2023-07-12','16:40', 40)
  , ('2023-07-12','16:59', 40)
  , ('2023-07-12','17:00', 40)
  , ('2023-07-12','17:45', 50)
  ;
```

```
set @MinutosIntervalo := 20; 
set @FechaIni := cast('2023-07-01' as date);
set @FechaFin := cast('2023-07-31' as date);
set @HoraIni := cast('08:00:00' as time);
set @HoraFin := cast('17:30:00' as time);
set @IntervaloDia := timediff(@HoraFin, @HoraIni);
set @MinutosTotales = hour(@IntervaloDia) * 60 + minute(@IntervaloDia);
set @Intervalos = @MinutosTotales / @MinutosIntervalo;

with
Intervalo as (
select   GenInt.NumIntervalo
       , addtime(@HoraIni, ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) div 60 * 10000 + ((GenInt.NumIntervalo - 1) * @MinutosIntervalo) % 60 * 100) InicioIntervalo
       , addtime(@HoraIni, (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) div 60 * 10000 + (GenInt.NumIntervalo * @MinutosIntervalo - 1) % 60 * 100 + 59) FinIntervalo
  from (select row_number() over (order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as NumIntervalo from information_schema.columns) as GenInt
 where GenInt.NumIntervalo <= @Intervalos + case when mod(@Intervalos, 1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
)
select   t.fecha
       , i.InicioIntervalo
       , i.FinIntervalo
       , count(*) NumeroRegistros
       , sum(t.Importe) ImporteTotal
  from Intervalo i
       inner join latabla t on t.hora between i.InicioIntervalo and i.FinIntervalo
 where t.fecha between @FechaIni and @FechaFin
   and t.hora between @HoraIni and @HoraFin
 group by t.fecha
       , i.InicioIntervalo
       , i.FinIntervalo
 order by t.fecha, i.InicioIntervalo  
  ;
```

He probado todo en un [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eiOygSd6) con estos resultados:

Intervalos de 20 minutos:

| fecha | InicioIntervalo | FinIntervalo | NumeroRegistros | ImporteTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-09 | 10:00:00 | 10:19:59 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-07-09 | 11:00:00 | 11:19:59 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-07-09 | 11:20:00 | 11:39:59 | 2 | 25 |
| 2023-07-10 | 11:00:00 | 11:19:59 | 1 | 20 |
| 2023-07-11 | 12:00:00 | 12:19:59 | 1 | 30 |
| 2023-07-12 | 13:00:00 | 13:19:59 | 1 | 40 |
| 2023-07-12 | 16:40:00 | 16:59:59 | 2 | 80 |
| 2023-07-12 | 17:00:00 | 17:19:59 | 1 | 40 |

Intervalos de 120 minutos:

| fecha | InicioIntervalo | FinIntervalo | NumeroRegistros | ImporteTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-09 | 10:00:00 | 11:59:59 | 5 | 65 |
| 2023-07-10 | 10:00:00 | 11:59:59 | 1 | 20 |
| 2023-07-11 | 12:00:00 | 13:59:59 | 1 | 30 |
| 2023-07-12 | 12:00:00 | 13:59:59 | 1 | 40 |
| 2023-07-12 | 16:00:00 | 17:59:59 | 3 | 120 |

Intervalos de 5 minutos:

| fecha | InicioIntervalo | FinIntervalo | NumeroRegistros | ImporteTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-09 | 10:00:00 | 10:04:59 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-07-09 | 10:15:00 | 10:19:59 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-07-09 | 11:15:00 | 11:19:59 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-07-09 | 11:25:00 | 11:29:59 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-07-09 | 11:30:00 | 11:34:59 | 1 | 15 |
| 2023-07-10 | 11:00:00 | 11:04:59 | 1 | 20 |
| 2023-07-11 | 12:00:00 | 12:04:59 | 1 | 30 |
| 2023-07-12 | 13:00:00 | 13:04:59 | 1 | 40 |
| 2023-07-12 | 16:40:00 | 16:44:59 | 1 | 40 |
| 2023-07-12 | 16:55:00 | 16:59:59 | 1 | 40 |
| 2023-07-12 | 17:00:00 | 17:04:59 | 1 | 40 |

Answer (score -3):

Para obtener la suma de los remitos en cada intervalo de tiempo especificado, puedes utilizar la función GROUP BY en MySQL. Esta función te permite agrupar los registros por intervalos de tiempo y luego aplicar la función SUM para obtener la suma de los importes en cada grupo.

Aquí tienes una consulta que puedes utilizar como punto de partida:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(fecha, ' ', TIME_FORMAT(TIME(hora), '%H:%i')) AS intervalo,
    SUM(importe) AS suma_remitos
FROM 
    latabla
WHERE 
    fecha >= '2022-01-01' AND fecha <= '2023-06-30'
    AND hora >= '09:00:00' AND hora <= '21:30:00'
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(fecha, ' ', FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(hora) / (30*60)) * (30*60))
ORDER BY 
    fecha, hora
```

Explicación de la consulta:

Utilizamos la función CONCAT para combinar la fecha y la hora en un solo campo llamado "intervalo". También utilizamos TIME_FORMAT para formatear la hora en el formato HH:mm.
Aplicamos la función SUM en el campo "importe" para obtener la suma de los importes en cada grupo.
El WHERE filtra los registros por las fechas y horas especificadas.
El GROUP BY agrupa los registros por intervalos de tiempo. Utilizamos CONCAT nuevamente para agrupar por la fecha y el intervalo de tiempo específico, calculado con FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(hora) / (30*60)) * (30*60), que redondea la hora al intervalo de 30 minutos.
El ORDER BY ordena los resultados por fecha y hora.
Esta consulta te devolverá los intervalos de tiempo con la suma de los importes correspondientes a cada intervalo.

Recuerda ajustar las fechas y horas según tus requerimientos.

¡Espero que esto te ayude! Si tienes más preguntas, no dudes en hacerlas.

## EDITO PARA RESPONDER A TU CONSULTA ADICIONAL

Comentas:

> Ahora, en la cláusula select, en concat(), para mostrar el resultado, toma la hora del primer resultado que se encuentre. Cómo quedaría ese concat() para que muestre, por ejemplo: 2022-01-03 09:30:00 - 10:00:00? –

Si te estoy entendiendo bien, prueba con:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', 
        DATE_FORMAT(TIME(hora), '%H:%i'), ' - ', 
        DATE_FORMAT(
            ADDTIME(TIME(hora), SEC_TO_TIME(30*60)),
            '%H:%i'
        )
    ) AS intervalo,
    SUM(importe) AS suma_remitos
FROM 
    latabla
WHERE 
    fecha >= '2022-01-01' AND fecha <= '2023-06-30'
    AND hora >= '09:00:00' AND hora <= '21:30:00'
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(fecha, ' ', FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(hora) / (30*60)) * (30*60))
ORDER BY 
    fecha, hora
```

Si usas DATE_FORMAT() puedes formatear la fecha y la hora. También se utiliza ADDTIME() y SEC_TO_TIME() para agregar 30 minutos a la hora inicial y luego formatearla correctamente.

Con esta modificación, la función CONCAT() mostrará los resultados en el formato solicitado, por ejemplo: "2022-01-03 09:30:00 - 10:00:00".

Ya me dices si te sirve de ayuda.
Gracias

Comment: Ahora, en la cláusula `select`, en `concat()`, para mostrar el resultado, toma la hora del primer resultado que se encuentre. Cómo quedaría ese `concat()` para que muestre, por ejemplo: `2022-01-03 09:30:00 - 10:00:00`?

Comment: @julio Ojo que usó alguna implementación de GPT para su respuesta... A ver si logra responderte ;)

Comment: @padaleiana No se habían prohibido las IA? cómo me daría cuenta de eso?

Comment: @julio No es complicado reconocerlo: fijate por ejemplo la última oración (que incluso se repite en [otras respuestas](/a/598849)), o la primera oración, que dice "para hacer <lo que dice tu pregunta>, debes hacer <la pseudo respuesta>. Hay muchos otros patrones, pero dejo eso por el momento. La detección se va afinando viendo una y otra vez lo mismo :)

Comment: @julio prueba la función DATE_FORMAT() y con ella puedes establecer condicionales.

Por ejemplo:

SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', 
        DATE_FORMAT(TIME(hora), '%H:%i'), ' - ', 
 
Te amplío la respuesta abajo.

Comment: @CristianSarabiaMartínez sé algo de MySQ y eso no responde a mi planteo.Si se está sumando el intervalo de 9:30 a 10, me gustaría que la salida sea: `2022-01-03 9:30 - 10:00` y no la salida actual: `2022-01-03 9:32 - 10:02`. La edición de tu respuesta, sigue tomando la primera hora en la que encuentra algo para sumar y a esa hora le suma el intervalo (eso está bien), pero el resultado no es lo que necesito

Comment: @padaleiana ni le presté atención a esa última frase. Me refería al código. Porque he probado algún que otro GPT para ver propuestas a códigos que ya tengo funcionando correctamente y las soluciones ofrecidas no estaban, en la mayoría de los casos, mejor optimizadas que mi código.

Comment: @Julio ¿en realidad esto te está funcionando? Leo la respuesta y no lo creo...

Comment: @jachguate no sé qué decirte... lo estoy probando aún. Qué es lo que mas te llama la atención?

Comment: @julio La forma de formar los _intervalos_, para comenzar, pues no va a agrupar como creo que lo necesitas, y luego que potencialmente excluye información de los días intermedios. Lamentablemente nunca respondiste a mi comentario en la pregunta para intentar armar yo mi propia respuesta. Si no estás seguro si te va a funcionar ¿por qué la marcaste como aceptada?.

Comment: @jachguate la respuesta corta es que vi la respuesta esta y la de David JP y buscaba una única consulta. Para no hacer tan larga la conversación vamos al chat. Pero si, no voy a aceptar esta respuesta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147196/discussion-between-jachguate-and-julio).